# Functions - Model, Controller

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

In my model I have this function that defines the format of the url:

```
 public function url_format_category($category, $lang_domin) {
    if (lang('abbr') == 'en_US')
        $lang_domin = 'en/';
    else if (lang('abbr') == 'es_US')
        $lang_domin = 'es/';

    if (is_array($category))  
        $category = (object) $category; 

    if($category->title != '') {
        $return = strtolower(url_title($category->title)).'-cmdo-'.$category->id;
    }else{
        $return = 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$category->id;
    }   

    return $return;   
}
```

And the Controller have the function that checks if the url is right and redirects if I'm wrong:

```
if($this->uri->uri_string != $this->learn->url_format_category($data['category'], $lang_domin)) {
 redirect($this->learn->url_format_category($data['category'], $lang_domin),'location','301');
exit;
 }
```

But now I have to do the same thing with a URL that does not contain a Model, then wanted to know if I can create these two functions in the Controller (together or separately) and how it could do that. Is it possible?

Note: I'm using CodeIgniter

Comment: You'll need to move that function to a library or a helper that can be loaded on pages that don't need the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may move this function into your own function helper file and also you can auto load the file, for example, create a helper file in `application/helpers` folder as `functions_helper.php` and declare/define this function in this file then add the following line in in your `application/config/autoload.php` file:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('functions_helper');
```

Now you can use the function just like any other `PHP` function. For example:

```
url_format_category($data['category'], $lang_domin);
```

This is the simplest way to reuse common helper functions (Using a helper).